# Loop through data attributes and create an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach, attributes

I have many div elements that in turn have many data attributes.

For each element I want to build an array containing the names and values of the data attributes.

My code looks like this:-

```
$( "#"+progWindowID ".newItem" ).each( function() {
  var itemData = {
    elemCategory   : $(this).attr( 'data-Category' ),
    elemType       : $(this).attr( 'data-Type' ),
    elemName       : $(this).attr( 'data-Name' ),
    elemTop        : $(this).attr( 'data-Top' ),
    elemLeft       : $(this).attr( 'data-Left' ),
    elemHeight     : $(this).attr( 'data-Height' ),
    elemWidth      : $(this).attr( 'data-Width' ),
    elemCreatedBy  : $(this).attr( 'data-CreatedBy' ),
    elemCreatedOn  : $(this).attr( 'data-CreatedOn' )
  };
}
```

Can I loop through the data attributes to build the array using each data attribute's name as a key in the array? Then when I add more data attributes later my code will still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `$(obj).data();` it will give you a hash of the properties.

Example:

```
 $( "#"+progWindowID ".newItem" ).each( function() {
   var itemData = $(this).data();
  });
```

jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Yeah simply hash manipulation would take care of that, but for his stated intent this would work.

Comment: Cool @Zach, I will simply put "elem" in front of my data keys! And thank you for the documentation link